# Merge Rows AND/OR Columns into one field in a GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL table looks like

```
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| rid | ship_to_id | product_code | product_name | first_row | second_row | third_row |
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|   1 |        555 | A            | Crystal      | 1         | 2          | 3         |
|   1 |        555 | A            | Crystal      | 4         | 5          | 6         |
|   2 |        333 | B            | Diamond      | first     | second     | third     |
|   2 |        333 | A            | Crystal      | ROW 1     | ROW 2      | ROW 3     |
|   2 |        333 | A            | Crystal      | ROW 4     | ROW 5      | ROW 6     |
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

And I am trying to get following results

```
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
| rid | ship_to_id | product_name |                data                 |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
|   1 |        555 | Crystal      | 1 2 3 4 5 6                         |
|   2 |        333 | Diamond      | first second third                  |
|   2 |        333 | Crystal      | ROW 1 ROW 2 ROW 3 ROW 4 ROW 5 ROW 6 |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code. Thanks

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable group by rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "$row[rid] $row[ship_to_id] $row[product_code] $row[product_name] $row[first_row] $row[second_row] $row[third_row] <br>";
}
```

Comment: I read your question twice but I still can't get what you are trying to do. Can you rephrase please?

Comment: Thank you for taking interest :) Actually I am trying to display results merging first_row, second_row, third_row based on the match from other columns. Say if ship_to_id and product_code matches I need it to group first_row, second_row and third_row into one single row for example: for first two rows it should display '1 555 Crystal 1 2 3 4 5 6' Let me know if it makes some sense

Comment: 1. See normalization. 2. See 1.

Comment: @Strawberry: I think he already answered to this suggestion with "2) Possibly, but according to given scenario I would have to go this way." - I think this means that the structure is given and not allowed to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're forgetting product_code sometimes, I guess.
2. This probably is bad database design. You should learn about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and related techniques.
3. Third, SQL normally produces the same number of columns for every result record, so the best result you could have has rows like `1, 555, "A", "Crystal", "1 4 2 5 3 6"` (notice these are 5 values). But I cannot think of a concatenation method that would produce the numbers in the 1 2 3 4 5 6 order. Depending on the better form of your database-schema-to-be, this might be something easier done in PHP than SQL.

If you're still up to concatenating all values into a single cell (as in the newly formatted example output), the you should try something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(first_row,'#',second_row,'#',third_row) SEPARATOR '~') AS data
FROM tablename
GROUP BY rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name;
```

Notice that the values of first_row etc. are separated by a '#' and the values from distinct records by a '~' sign. You can find more options in the [documentation of MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: The problem with concatenations in general is that you cannot say which 3 values "ROW 1 ROW 1 ROW" was created from, because the fields are delimited with a string (space) the fields themselves may contain.

Comment: I agree with you that concatenation is a poor solution in this case, however it is worth to mention that the delimiter character can be parametrized, so at least the situation it is not as bad as you describe, when some rules applies to the data in that 3 columns :)

Comment: Then yours is the lucky exception I meant to exclude when saying "in general". If you can assure a delimiter that's never-ever present in the values then you probably good with Rahul's answer. But in some cases (especially if this is not the very final result) concatenation may prove to have bad performance (if you're splitting it up later then there was probably no point in concatenation).

Comment: 1) Yes we can skip any of product_code or product_name
2) Possibly, but according to given scenario I would have to go this way.
3) I can not merge first_row,second_row,third_row into one column because each column is a string of 25 characters and in the end I will have no way to recognize sentence/row break.

Comment: You wrote to 3) that you cannot merge them, but also edited the original question to include exactly that desired result. Sou you should first decide whether a single data field of e.g. "ROW 1,ROW 2,..." is something you want, or as per the above comment that is not acceptable, because of not being unambiguously splittable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I didn't edited the original question and no I can not merge them into one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was Marty who edited the question (added formating). But as you say, the modification's obviously wrong, because he put the results in a single cell. Please edit your question to reflect how you wish to get your data back in a fixed number of rows. Remember, in SQL the result sets are rectangular; each row has the same number of columns.

Comment: No problem man. Anyway is there a way to get results as per Marty's edit I mean in a single cell? If so I can make it work too. Actually all I want is to group first_row, second_row and third_row where product_name is same and rid is unique. Thanks

Comment: I have written the details of the single-cell solution to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you group by the first 4 columns and use no aggregation function on the remaining ones, data will be lost when multiple record have the same values in the columns grouped by.
So basically the result will be like the following:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------+
| rid | ship_to_id | product_name | first_row | second_row | thrid_row |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------+
|   1 |        555 | Crystal      | 1         | 2          | 3         |
|   2 |        333 | Diamond      | first     | second     | third     |
|   2 |        333 | Crystal      | ROW 1     | ROW 2      | ROW 3     |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------+
```

That's what group by means. To keep the data of the fields containing varying data, you must use an aggregation function on them, like [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Example:

```
SELECT rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(first_row), GROUP_CONCAT(second_row), GROUP_CONCAT(third_row)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name
```

This will concatenate the values of the corresponding record like this:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
| rid | ship_to_id | product_name |  first_row  |  second_row  |  thrid_row  |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|   1 |        555 | Crystal      | 1 4         | 2 5          | 3 6         |
|   2 |        333 | Diamond      | first       | second       | third       |
|   2 |        333 | Crystal      | ROW 1 ROW 4 | ROW 2 ROW 5  | ROW 3 ROW 6 |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

However, your approach with `GROUP BY` is probably not be the best for this case. It would worth to think about to just order by the `rid, ship_to_id, product_code, product_name` columns, and then iterate through them in PHP with the given order and merge the corresponding rows there.

You may also have to reconsider you database design, as a query like this smells about a bad concept :)

Comment: Yes, what you are saying makes sense but this is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. Actually it will check for ship_to_id and group same product_name against each ship_to_id then corresponding first_row, second_row, third_row in one line/row. I tried iterating through PHP here http://pastebin.com/9FXS2NAQ Still its not giving accurate results. Yeah database design could be poor but I couldn't think of a better design in that scenario :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
select rid,ship_to_id,product_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(first_row,' ',second_row,' ',third_row) as new_val
from mytable
group by rid,ship_to_id,product_name;
```